# Items not rendering when they should in apex:selectOption

Tags: visualforce, selectoption

I am using a picklist to control navigation. This is controlled through a huge list of items that are displayed on screen.

```
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Edit Task Status" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Development_Plan_Task__c))}" itemvalue="DEVP|"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Launch Skillsoft" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'SkillSoft'}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.lmscons__ConsumerDirector}?action=LaunchContent&tuId={!curr_i.item.assignment.lmscons__Training_User_License__c}')"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="View Details SS" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'SkillSoft'}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.Details}?id={!curr_i.item.module.Id}&type=SSModule&asnmt={!curr_i.item.Assignment.ID}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Launch Learning" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName != 'SkillSoft' && ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId) && ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmscons__Quiz__c)}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.lmscons__ConsumerDirector}?action=LaunchContent&tuId={!curr_i.item.assignment.lmscons__Training_User_License__c}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Launch Quiz" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName != 'SkillSoft' && ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId) && NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmscons__Quiz__c)) && ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c) && ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Development_Plan_Task__c)}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.lmscons__Quiz}?uid={!currentUserId}&id={!curr_i.item.module.lmscons__Quiz__c}&tlId={!curr_i.item.assignment.ID}&retUrl={!URLHome}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="View Details 2" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName != 'SkillSoft' && ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId) && ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c)}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.Details}?id={!curr_i.item.module.Id}&type=Module&asnmt={!curr_i.item.Assignment.ID}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="View Details 3" rendered="{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName != 'SkillSoft' && NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c)) && ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId)}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.Details}?id={!curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c}&type=Event&asnmt={!curr_i.item.Assignment.ID}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="View External Details" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId))}" itemvalue="DESC|{!$Page.FICOExternalTraining}?Id={!curr_i.ExternalTrainingId}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Rate/Review item" rendered="{!ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId) && ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Development_Plan_Task__c)}" itemvalue="REVW|{!$Page.Review}?type=Module&Lid={!curr_i.item.module.Id}"/>
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="Remove item" rendered="{!curr_i.item.assignment.CreatedBy.id == currentUserId}" itemvalue="DELM|{!curr_i.item.Assignment.ID}"/>
```

The RENDERS do not seem to be working so I added this:

```
<apex:selectOption itemlabel="type:'{!curr_i.item.module.RecordType.DeveloperName}'| ext:'{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.ExternalTrainingId))}' id:'{!curr_i.ExternalTrainingId}'| devPT:'{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Development_Plan_Task__c))}' id:'{!curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Development_Plan_Task__c}'| quiz:'{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmscons__Quiz__c))}' id:'{!curr_i.item.module.lmscons__Quiz__c}'| event:'{!NOT(ISNULL(curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c))}' id:'{!curr_i.item.module.lmsilt__Event__c}'" itemvalue="DEVP|"/>
```

which gives me this:

> type:'Module'| ext:'false' id:''| devPT:'false' id:''| quiz:'true' id:'SOMEID'| event:'false' id:''

for a quiz.

> type:'Module'| ext:'false' id:''| devPT:'false' id:''| quiz:'false' id:''| event:'false' id:''

for a standard module

so I can tell when a row SHOULD render but most of these rows only render when I remove all of the renders.

Anyone have any other information? What am I missing?

Comment: If you gave one example of an apex:selectOption that didn't render and the debug output for that it would be easier to comment. Another way to accomplish this is to create `SelectionOption` objects in the controller and include them in the page via an `apex:selectOptions` tag. That way you can create Apex unit tests and use those to get the logic right (and continue to assert that it is right in the future).

Comment: I concur with @BarCotter. You are going to be far better off putting all of this logic into a controller, and then leveraging a single line of <apex:selectOptions value="{!myfinalSetOfValues}"/>

Comment: This option list appears on a vfpage that displays a very large list of data on screen, each row with its own list of Options. Would it be best to move this into a Map of id to list<selectOption>?